# CTE Group By not grouping results correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following CTE that is doing a SUM on the field MERCHANDISE_AMT, separately from the below two queries and then I'm joining those results together in the final select. I'm having a problem with the Group By on either the inner queries and/or the final Select statement. I want to be able to group the LINE_NBR and PO_DIST_LINE_NUM together so that I have 2 rows as the final output. I need to have these columns selected though in order to reference them in the Join on the final query.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
        A.BUSINESS_UNIT, 
        A.PO_ID,  
        A.PO_TYPE, 
        A.PO_STATUS, 
        (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PO_DT,121)) AS PO_DT, 
        A.VENDOR_SETID, 
        A.VENDOR_ID, 
        A.BUYER_ID, 
        D.DEPTID, 
        D.LINE_NBR, 
        D.SCHED_NBR, 
        D.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM,
        SUM(D.MERCHANDISE_AMT) AS SUM_MERCH,  
        E.SETID + '_' + E.DEPTID AS REQUESTOR, 
        H.ROLEUSER_SUPR
    FROM 
        PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB D 
            INNER JOIN PS_PO_LINE C 
                ON  D.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT 
                AND D.PO_ID = C.PO_ID 
                AND D.LINE_NBR = C.LINE_NBR 
                INNER JOIN PS_PO_HDR A 
                    ON C.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                    AND C.PO_ID = A.PO_ID 
                    AND A.PO_TYPE IN ('AGR','BO')
                    AND A.PO_STATUS IN ('A','D','O')
            INNER JOIN PS_DEPT_TBL E 
                ON D.DEPTID = E.DEPTID 
                AND D.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL = E.SETID 
                AND E.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) 
                                    FROM PS_DEPT_TBL A_ED
                                    WHERE E.SETID = A_ED.SETID
                                        AND E.DEPTID = A_ED.DEPTID
                                        AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10))


                INNER JOIN PS_ROLEXLATOPR H 
                    ON E.SETID + '_' +   E.DEPTID = H.ROLEUSER 
    WHERE 
            D.PO_ID = 'J010000185'
        AND D.BUSINESS_UNIT = '50000'
    GROUP BY 
        A.BUSINESS_UNIT,
        A.PO_ID, 
        A.PO_TYPE, 
        A.PO_STATUS, 
        (CONVERT(CHAR(10), A.PO_DT, 121)), 
        A.VENDOR_SETID, 
        A.VENDOR_ID, 
        A.BUYER_ID, 
        D.DEPTID, 
        E.SETID + '_' + E.DEPTID, 
        H.ROLEUSER_SUPR, 
        D.LINE_NBR, 
        D.SCHED_NBR, 
        D.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM ), 

CTE2 AS (
SELECT 
        A.BUSINESS_UNIT, 
        A.PO_ID,  
        A.PO_TYPE, 
        A.PO_STATUS, 
        (CONVERT(CHAR(10), A.PO_DT, 121)) AS PO_DT, 
        A.VENDOR_SETID, 
        A.VENDOR_ID, 
        A.BUYER_ID, 
        G.DEPTID, 
        H.ROLEUSER_SUPR, 
        SUM(G.MERCHANDISE_AMT) AS SUM_MERCH, 
        G.BUSINESS_UNIT_PO, 
        G.SCHED_NBR, 
        G.LINE_NBR, 
        G.PO_DIST_LINE_NUM
    FROM 
        PS_DISTRIB_LINE G
            INNER JOIN  PS_PO_LINE C 
                ON  G.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT 
                AND G.PO_ID = C.PO_ID 
                AND G.LINE_NBR = C.LINE_NBR
                INNER JOIN PS_PO_HDR A 
                    ON C.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                    AND C.PO_ID = A.PO_ID
            INNER JOIN PS_DEPT_TBL E 
                ON  G.DEPTID = E.DEPTID
                AND G.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL = E.SETID 
                AND E.EFFDT = ( SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) 
                                    FROM PS_DEPT_TBL A_ED
                                    WHERE E.SETID = A_ED.SETID
                                    AND E.DEPTID = A_ED.DEPTID
                                    AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10))
                INNER JOIN PS_ROLEXLATOPR H 
                    ON E.SETID + '_' + E.DEPTID = H.ROLEUSER
    WHERE 
            G.BUSINESS_UNIT = '50000'
        AND G.PO_ID = 'J010000185'
    GROUP BY 
        A.BUSINESS_UNIT,
        A.PO_ID, 
        A.PO_TYPE, 
        A.PO_STATUS, 
        (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PO_DT,121)), 
        A.VENDOR_SETID, 
        A.VENDOR_ID, 
        A.BUYER_ID, 
        G.DEPTID,  
        H.ROLEUSER_SUPR,
        G.BUSINESS_UNIT_PO,
        G.SCHED_NBR, 
        G.PO_DIST_LINE_NUM, 
        G.LINE_NBR,  
        E.SETID + '_' + E.DEPTID, 
        G.PO_DIST_LINE_NUM, 
        G.LINE_NBR )


SELECT DISTINCT  
        D.REQUESTOR, 
        D.BUSINESS_UNIT, 
        D.PO_ID, 
        D.PO_TYPE, 
        D.PO_STATUS, 
        (CONVERT(CHAR(10),D.PO_DT,121)), 
        D.VENDOR_SETID, 
        D.VENDOR_ID, 
        D.BUYER_ID, 
        D.DEPTID, 
        D.ROLEUSER_SUPR, 
        NULLIF((G.SUM_MERCH / D.SUM_MERCH),0) AS 'Threshold'
    FROM 
        CTE D
            LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE2 G 
                ON D.PO_ID = G.PO_ID
                AND D.BUSINESS_UNIT = G.BUSINESS_UNIT_PO 
                AND D.SCHED_NBR = G.SCHED_NBR 
                AND D.LINE_NBR = G.LINE_NBR 
                AND D.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM = G.PO_DIST_LINE_NUM
```

Here is the current output:

```
REQUESTOR   BUSINESS_UNIT   PO_ID       PO_TYPE  PO_STATUS  (No column name)    VENDOR_SETID    VENDOR_ID   BUYER_ID    DEPTID  ROLEUSER_SUPR   Threshold
11000_744   50000           J010000185  AGR      D          2017-05-30          SHARE           90238A      EDARPINO    744     TVORHIS         0.557487
11000_744   50000           J010000185  AGR      D          2017-05-30          SHARE           90238A      EDARPINO    744     TVORHIS         0.750000
41000_744   50000           J010000185  AGR      D          2017-05-30          SHARE           90238A      EDARPINO    744     MHOPSON         0.557487
41000_744   50000           J010000185  AGR      D          2017-05-30          SHARE           90238A      EDARPINO    744     MHOPSON         0.750000
```

Desired final output would be the following:

```
REQUESTOR   BUSINESS_UNIT   PO_ID       PO_TYPE  PO_STATUS  (No column name)    VENDOR_SETID    VENDOR_ID   BUYER_ID    DEPTID  ROLEUSER_SUPR  Threshold
11000_744   50000           J010000185  AGR      D          2017-05-30          SHARE           90238A      EDARPINO    744     TVORHIS       .7209
41000_744   50000           J010000185  AGR      D          2017-05-30          SHARE           90238A      EDARPINO    744     MHOPSON       .7094
```

The problem is that the 'Threshold' field calculation is being broken out separately per REQUESTOR, I believe because of the field DISTRIB_LINE_NUM from the 1st CTE query (Alias 'CTE'). If I remove the DISTRIB_LINE_NUM column from the 1st query I get an output of 2 rows, but in order to do the join in the final query it appears that I need to do a select on the field in the 1st query, in order to be able to reference it in the join in the final select query (unless there is a way around this).

I don't believe there is a way to select a non-aggregate column, and then not have to use it in the Group By, so I am looking for a solution this. If there's a way to apply a Group By to the final select so that the four rows are grouped into two, by REQUESTOR , or alternatively by modifying the inner queries Group By?

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but...  Why are you including the DISTRIB_LINE_NUM in the group by for the final select if you don't actually want to group on it?  `AND G.PO_DIST_LINE_NUM = D.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM`

Answer (score 0):

Below should work. The idea is you merge your files, then summarize group level and get your values in the same line, then find a treshold on the result. Pay attention - create alias for your PO_DT value after transformation.

```
Select REQUESTOR, BUSINESS_UNIT, PO_ID, PO_TYPE, PO_STATUS, PO_DT, VENDOR_SETID, VENDOR_ID, BUYER_ID, DEPTID, ROLEUSER_SUPR, NULLIF((SUM_MERCHA / SUM_MERCHB),0) AS 'Threshold' from
(
Select REQUESTOR, BUSINESS_UNIT, PO_ID, PO_TYPE, PO_STATUS, PO_DT, VENDOR_SETID, VENDOR_ID, BUYER_ID, DEPTID, ROLEUSER_SUPR, SUM(SUM_MERCHA) as SUM_MERCHA, SUM(SUM_MERCHB) as SUM_MERCHB from (
SELECT DISTINCT  D.REQUESTOR, D.BUSINESS_UNIT, D.PO_ID, D.PO_TYPE, D.PO_STATUS, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),D.PO_DT,121)) as PO_DT, D.VENDOR_SETID, D.VENDOR_ID, D.BUYER_ID, D.DEPTID, D.ROLEUSER_SUPR, G.MERCHANDISE_AMT as SUM_MERCHA,  D.MERCHANDISE_AMT as SUM_MERCHB
FROM CTE D
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE2 G ON G.PO_ID = D.PO_ID AND G.BUSINESS_UNIT_PO = D.BUSINESS_UNIT  AND G.SCHED_NBR = D.SCHED_NBR AND G.LINE_NBR = D.LINE_NBR AND G.PO_DIST_LINE_NUM = D.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM)
Group by D.REQUESTOR, D.BUSINESS_UNIT, D.PO_ID, D.PO_TYPE, D.PO_STATUS, PO_DT, D.VENDOR_SETID, D.VENDOR_ID, D.BUYER_ID, D.DEPTID, D.ROLEUSER_SUPR) E ) F
```

Comment: Oly I am getting a Syntax error when I run this - `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'.` Looks like its also error highlighting here on the last closing parenthesis between E and F.

Comment: Also the actual fields that I am doing the Threshold calculation are G.MERCHANDISE_AMT / D.MERCHANDISE_AMT, I think you referred to them as G.SUM_MERCH and D.SUM_MERCH though...

Comment: Order By is the last statement in the select block https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017. Updated the code, got typo around merchant_amt.

Comment: I am still getting the syntax error  `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 73
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'.`

Comment: Here is the code you have above combined with the rest of the query that has the syntax error, https://pastebin.com/W41V3sCC

Comment: If you have any other thoughts it would be appreciated.

Comment: Your expression with D table is in round brackets (). Try to call it with another character like DD, and adjust your Group By variables. Always try to break down the query to narrow down the error if the error description is not helpful. FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT  ...
FROM CTE D
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE2 ...)
GROUP BY D.REQUESTOR should be FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT  ...
FROM CTE D
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE2 ...) DD
GROUP BY DD.REQUESTOR